# How to share a value between all docker containers spun op by the same "docker-compose up" call?

Tags: docker, parameter-passing, docker-compose

### Context

We are migrating an older application to docker and as a first step we're working against some constraints. The database can not yet be put in a container, and moreover, it is shared between all developers in our team. So this question is to find a fix for a temporary problem.

To not clash with other developers using the same database, there is a system in place where each developer machine starts the application with a value that is unique to his machine. Each container should use this same value.

### Question

We are using `docker-compose` to start the containers. Is there a way to provide a (environment) variable to it that gets propagated to all containers?

### How I'm trying to do it:

My `docker-compose.yml` looks kind of like this:

```
my_service:
    image: my_service:latest
    command: ./my_service.sh
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    environment:
        - batch.id=${BATCH_ID}
```

then I thought running `BATCH_ID=$somevalue docker-compose up my_service` would fill in the `${BATCH_ID}`, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Is there another way? A better way?

**Optional:** Ideally everything should be contained so that a developer can just call `docker-compose up my_service` leading to compose itself calculating a value to pass to all the containers. But from what I see online, I think this is not possible.

Comment: You may use `env_file:`

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Alternatively you can just specify the env var name:

```
my_service:

    environment:
        - BATCH_ID
```

So the var `BATCH_ID` is defined from the current docker-compose execution scope; and passed to the container with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I changed, but suddenly it works as described.

---

`BATCH_ID` is the name of the environment variable on the host.
`batch.id` will be the name of the environment variable inside the container.

```
my_service:

    environment:
        - batch.id=${BATCH_ID}
```